# Using roo to create a springsource project with mongo

Tags: java, jpa, mongodb, spring-roo

**Preface:** I am coming from a .NET and PHP backround. I'm pretty comfortable with making a console app in Java. I've never used an ORM on any platform. I'm trying to learn enterprise java best practices. Therefore, if I sound ignorant, its probably because I am.

I downloaded the latest version of the [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts). I want to make a spring project with a JPA mongo (adapter/driver/driver whatever). I'd like to do so with roo. So what I think I need to know is the name of a JPA library that has a mongodb driver.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera), it's a JPA 1.0 ORM library for the Cassandra/Hbase/MongoDB database.  For info about getting started, see this blog post: [Working with MongoDB using Kundera](http://recipes4geeks.com/2011/05/02/working-with-mongodb-using-kundera/).

Comment: Ok I'll look into installing that with Maven, and making a springsource project with roo that uses that

Comment: I had to build it from SVN because the only directions for getting it from a remote maven repo gave me 1.0 with no mongodb support. I had to manually edit my `pom.xml` to make the local repo copy of kundera a dependency of my project. Tonight I will finish the sample and if it works mark you correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please try newer version of Kundera, i.e. 2.0.1. It has gone a major change since its inception and I see a lot of new features getting added and bugs being fixed. Currently it supports JPA 1.0 and Cassandra 0.7.6/ HBase/ MongoDB but we are planning to add support for Cassandra 0.8 and JPA 2.0 very soon. There is a pretty good example here: https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring data mongodb](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/), is not JPA but is easy to use. Also, [Spring roo has support to use it as persistence layer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html#d4e1991).

Good luck.