# I did a mvn install to kundera. I want to add the installed jar to another maven project

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, kundera

**Prefix:** I'm very new to maven so I am open to "your doing it wrong" answers.

I want to build a [kundera](http://code.google.com/p/kundera/) project with [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) as the backend. I tried [these directions](http://code.google.com/p/kundera/wiki/MavenUsage) but ended up with a kundera without the Document class. I was trying [this tutorial](http://xamry.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/working-with-mongodb-using-kundera/) that I got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079461/using-roo-to-create-a-springsource-project-with-mongo/6079901#6079901), and came to the conclusion that the version of kundera in that jar did not have mongo support. So I built kundera from svn and did a [`mvn install`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html). I want to know what mvn command or what edits to the `pom.xml` file I must make to add the kendera jar I just installed to my local maven repository as a dependency to another maven project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this into your pom under the `<repositories>` section.

```
    <repository>
        <id>kundera-missing</id>
        <name>Kundera Public Missing Resources Repository</name>
        <url>http://kundera.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/maven-missing-resources</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

And add a depedency like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.impetus.kundera</groupId>
        <artifactId>kundera</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

into your pom.xml
That should solve yuour problem.

You can join this forum for discussions related to Kundera:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kundera-discuss

Regards,
Amresh

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Is their no mvn command to add a dependency from a local repository? This seems like a manual step that could be eliminated.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt if there is any such plugin available with maven. Unfortunately you need to do it manually.